Text with color around the character (no shadow)
I am trying to mimic this text style:

It's pretty straightforward: a Text with a yellow background and a black border. However applying a border to a Text will just add a border around the whole view and not individual characters.
I tried using the shadow modifier, but that doesn't look that great. Any recommendations?

I guess that with AttributedString you should be able to do it.

Side note: I tried with AttributeContainer which has bridge to UIKit (and NSAttributedString) with container.strokeColor and container.strokeWidth but without success... It was like they were ignored, while other settings to the container worked (like foreground color). I managed to do it using a UILabel and directly NSAttributedString (there are question about NSAttributedString + Stroke & UILabel + SwiftUI).
